# What comics appear in the Marvel intro?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Before every Marvel movie there is an intro created from comics pages.

[image: Marvel intro]

What comics were used for Marvel intro?

Comment: should this go to movies or comics? Seems off topic here

Comment: @NKCampbell Why? The site takes comic book and movie questions and takes in and out of universe questions.

Comment: I guess I thought there was a comics SE but seems like there isn't? In that case, this site is probably as good or better than movies.

Comment: It's not the same comics for every movie.  Pick one movie.

Comment: @Kyle It's more than one intro? I thought it's the same for every movie.

Comment: @janisz: somehow, somewhere in the budget, they found the money to make more than one intro.

Comment: @KyleJones: If that is true, you should expand upon that sentiment and make it an answer that is a partial question challenge. Because I'm positive most people wouldn't know that.

Comment: I know for sure there's at least three different intros featuring different comics.  Some of them *are* shared between movies.

Comment: I'm sure the newest one contains footage from the earlier films as well,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is more than one flipbook Marvel intro.  By far the one I've seen the most often is the one I've nicknamed "Fist Kooom" because it describes the panel that was easiest for me to spot and remember film to film.

[image: fist kooom]

The panels flip and gradually fade into a flat white on red Marvel logo. **This is the intro featured in the animated gif attached to the question.**   Most Marvel films use this intro or a variant of it where some panels are added that are relevant to the particular film.  For example, the first Fantastic Four film used a variant of Fist Kooom with FF specific panels added at the beginning.  *Ghost Rider* got a similar treatment, with themed panels scattered throughout the usual Fist Kooom panels.

Sometime in 2013 Marvel started using an intro I call "Get Off Me", named for the speech balloon prominent in one striking panel.

[image: get off me]

This is the intro with the 3D Marvel logo slowly tumbling into view with the comics panels overlaid.  Fist Kooom was still used for several films after this new intro premiered.

Some movies got completely custom intros.  The second Fantastic Four movie, *Rise of the Silver Surfer*, was one such.  This featured a blue tinted intro that I've seen nowhere else that I call "Ain't Going No Nowhere".

[image: ain't going no where]

*Hulk* (not to be confused with *The Incredible Hulk*, which used Fist Kooom) also had a custom intro.  The panels were tinted green and lifted from Hulk comics.

[image: crawling guy in front of hulk]

*X-Men: The Last Stand* aka *X-Men 3* had a custom intro featuring panels from X-Men comics.

[image: i chose you says magneto]

*Elektra* got a custom intro, one of the earliest films to do so, along with *Hulk* the same year.  All the panels were from Elektra comics or otherwise Elektra-themed.

[image: elektra kills four]

Comment: What about the TV shows? Do they have different intros? Say *Jessica Jones* and *Iron Fist*.

Comment: Magneto met Pikachu???

Comment: @Adamant SHIELD uses the generic MCU one. The Netflix shows have their own, which doesn't look like any other one I've seen, but I _think_ includes panels from all 4 shows' comics.

Answer (score 8):

They differ based on the movie you're talking about. The comics are various issues that are relevant to the movie. For example, the X-Men movies show X-Men comics, the Fantastic Four movies used those characters, etc. Pre-MCU, I believe every movie basically got a "tweaked" one (some common panels, some unique to the movie); when the MCU came around, Marvel created a "standard" one used for all of those movies, though it's been redesigned a few times. You can see most of these [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DSVdL85F2E), at least up through 2012.

The one you included in your question appears to be an early MCU one, since they later switched to a [three-dimensional version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aXgR9oOJVU), and then [later still](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtuDYmxRwUU) added images from the movies themselves. As best as I can tell, the MCU intros include scenes from a variety of Avengers-based movies. I have picked out some obvious Iron Man and Captain America scenes, but also Captain Marvel, and what I believe to be Ant-Man and Doctor Strange. (I've never seen an panels that were clearly identifiable as Thor or The Incredible Hulk, oddly enough.)

Comment: The intro to *Thor: The Dark World* has a still of [Thor Girl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ph1o.jpg). Here's [her costume to compare](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/4/47589/1666940-tg.jpg), and notice the dialogue "Thus, if a storm", typical Thor-speak.

Comment: As I watch the intro frame-by-frame I get the impression that some scenes are taken from the same comic, but interspersed throughout the whole intro. There seems to be a "story" there about a missile with a panther logo on it that doesn't get intercepted and ends up exploding.

Comment: I _think_ there is an Iron Man comic that is broken up over the whole thing, which would make sense as that was the first MCU movie. There's a few scenes which appear to show the older style Iron Man face mask.

Comment: HULK REFUSE PUNY MARVEL PERMISSION TO REPRODUCE COMICS ON-SCREEN UNTIL HULK SEE DECENT SCRIPT FOR STANDALONE MOVIE AND GET PERCENTAGE OF BOX OFFICE AND MERCHANDISING